# How to distinguish between constant and non constant methods calling using operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a proxy that is used as the return type in containers instead of the actual data, to pros pond as much as possible the copying of the container until an actual change is made.

This is the method the returns the proxy :

```
Proxy operator[]( unsigned long index )
{
    return ( Proxy( *this, index ) );
}
```

Now the problem is when the container's data is user defined objects. I need a way to distinguish between the user calling constant and non constant methods of the instance, in order to know if a copying of the container needs to be done first.

For non constant methods I used the operator arrow :

```
Proxy
{
    ...

    UserDefinedObject* operaotr->() { return &m_instance; }

    UserDefinedObject* operaotr=>() { m_instance.CopyOnWrite(); return &m_instance; }

    ...

private:

    UserDefinedObject& m_instance;

    unsigned long m_index;

};
```

And now I try to find a way for the constant methods.

The problem is that this is the only operator that reapplies itself on the result, And the dot operator can not be overloaded.

Is there a way to overload another operator to have a similar behavior like operator arrow, or another way you can think of that will get me the desired behavior?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You might overload on constness...

Comment: is it on purpose that the `Proxy` always holds a non-const reference? If so, why bother about providing a way to call a const method?

Comment: because the proxy holds one instance of a container, and if the instance change all the container needs to be copied first because it is shared conatiner

Comment: i dont really understand. You want to call `.CopyOnWrite()` for calls to non-const member functions and not call it for calls to const member functions?

Comment: also not clear why it has to be the `operator->` you can make it two different member funtions and call them `proxy.get().some_mem_fun();` and `proxy.get_const().some_const_mem_fun();`

Comment: do you maybe want to write `proxy.??.mem_fun()` and depending on mem_fun being const or not the copy is made or not?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I need